# Why does lacking explicit type declaration in parameter work when function is used directly, but not when it is passed to another function?

Tags: rascal

Have this function defined in your module:

```
module Data

int inc(x) = x + 1;
```

Type this in the console:

```
rascal> import Data;
rascal> import List;
```

This works:

```
rascal> inc(1);
int: 2
```

But this does not:

```
rascal> list[int] y = [1,2,3];
rascal> mapper(y, inc); 
|rascal://<path>|: insert into collection not supported on value and int
☞ Advice
```

But it works if `inc(...)`'s parameter type is declared:

```
int inc(int x) = x + 1;
```

So why does not having this type declaration work for using the `inc(...)` function directly, but not for passing that function to `mapper(...)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because Rascal's type checker is still under development, you are not warned if you make a small mistake like forgetting to provide a type for a function parameter. It may still work, *accidentally*, in some circumstances but you are guaranteed to run into trouble somewhere as you've observed. The reason is that type inference for function parameters is simply not implemented as a feature. This is a language design decision with the intent of keeping error messages understandable.

So, this is not allowed:

```
int f(a) = a + 1;
```

And, it should be written like this:

```
int f(int a) = a + 1;
```

I consider it a bug that the interpreter doesn't complain about an untyped parameter. It is caused by the fact that we reuse the pattern matching code for both function parameters and inline patterns. [edit: issue has been registered at https://github.com/cwi-swat/rascal/issues/763]

In your case the example works because *dynamically* the type of the value is `int` and addition does not check the parameter types. The broken example breaks because the interpreter does checks the type of the function parameter at the call-site (which defaulted to `value` for the untyped parameter).

Comment: "I consider it a bug that the interpreter doesn't complain about an untyped parameter." - So should I file this as an issue?

Comment: well, that would be appreciated! The issue will then be solved as soon as we release the type checker. I don't think there is a good way of resolving it in the current code of the interpreter without a performance penalty.

Comment: Should I make two issues: one about using `inc(...)` directly, and one about using it in `mapper(...)`?

Comment: no, one issue is enough: "rascal does not report error when not declaring explicit type in function parameter" or something in this vain.

Comment: https://github.com/cwi-swat/rascal/issues/763 (maybe you'd like to edit this link into your answer.)